# JaxB cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an abstract class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<K> 
{

@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date cadastrado;
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date modificado;
@Column(length = 30)
private String ip;
private String autorModificacao;

public abstract K getId();

public abstract void setId(K id);
```

...

and a derived class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pessoa extends BaseEntity<Integer> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ColumnGridPF
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "pessoa")
    private Integer id;

....

@Override
Integer getId() {
  return id;
}

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

....

when my application try to unmarshall the object, I get an error

**

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at br.com.sigmaonline.entity.cadastro.pessoa.Pessoa.setId(Pessoa.java:46)
    at br.com.sigmaonline.entity.common.generic.BaseEntity$JaxbAccessorM_getId_setId_java_lang_Object.set(MethodAccessor_Ref.java:60)
```

**

Can Any one help me?

Comment: which implementation of JAXB are you using ? this code works fine with JDK (6 & 7) JAXB implementation (except you see namespace definitions in id element)

Answer (score 3):

By default when your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation is creating metadata for `Pessoa` it is also going to create metadata for the super class `BaseEntity`.  Since JAXB by default considers properties as mapped it is going to consider that it has a property called `id` of type `Object`.  When JAXB doesn't know the type of the property it will convert it to a DOM `Element`.  This is resulting in the `ClassCastException`.

**Solution**

The solution really depends upon whether or not you want `BaseEntity` considered part of the inheritance hierachy (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).  But what I would recommend is either leveraging `@XmlTransient` or `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` on `BaseType` to remove problematic properties:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html